# How to disable Flash in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to disable Flash for a test case where the user doesn't have Flash installed in Chrome.

Before updating, it worked fine with this option `--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash`. 
But now it doesn't work.

How do I disable Flash?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 25):

Do the following on your Google Chrome, to disable Flash, or allow it for specific domains:

### Option 1:

Navigate to `chrome://settings/content` and select the option you want in the **Flash** section.

---

### Option 2:

Chrome **Settings** > Click **Show advanced options...** > Under **Privacy** click **Content Settings...** > See the **Flash** section.

[image]

Comment: What I just learned: 
If Flash still is active even if "Block sites from running Flash" is marked, the tested website will have been (automatically!) added as exception!


To finally stop Flash (e.g. to be able to test an alternative option of your website with Javascript) open "Manage exceptions..." and search for that website address. 
Then make the wensite specific setting ("block") and finally Flash will give up ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way.

1. Go to the url you want to block flash for
2. Click on icon "i" in front of the url
3. Change the flash to "Always block for this site"

   [image: Press on "i" icon in front of the url and block the flash]

Answer (score 3):

I discovered something else that appears to disable Flash:  Navigate to

> chrome://flags/#prefer-html-over-flash

and set the flag that is highlighted (for "**Prefer HTML over Flash**") to "Enabled"

I have just done this and tested my computer on [Do I Leak](http://www.doileak.com)- and it reports that Flash is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Sadly they [removed interaction with plugins like that in chrome 57](https://betanews.com/2017/01/30/chrome-57-plugins/).

> With web browsers being among the most frequently used pieces of
>   software out there, it's little wonder that there is so much concern
>   about security surrounding them. Browser plugins can be a major
>   security worry, and with Chrome 57 Google has taken the strange
>   decision to block users from disabling them or changing their
>   settings.

You can still get at the settings by navigating to: chrome://settings/content

**Example**:
[image]

Alternatively you can get there by visiting:
Chrome Settings > Show advanced options... > Content Settings > Flash